# how get top dynamic in wheel

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I need to obtain the top position that always changes where the user use the mouse. I have a scrolUp and I need calculate top position to do some check and I do:

```
HostListener('window:wheel', ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll(event:any) {
    let element= document.getElementById('scrollUp');
    let positionTop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    console.log(positionTop);

}
```

I think that  `element.getBoundingClientRect().top` is not the correct solution to my problem, i need to ha somethink.Anyone can help me?

Comment: Without knowing what 'some check' is required to be it's not possible to help. Can you show just enough code to make it clear what value you need? I guess you know that .top is relative to the viewport - is that whatever the check is requires?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **MouseEvent** object provided by the wheel event. Try this:

---

```
HostListener('window:wheel', ['$event'])
onWindowScroll(event: WheelEvent) {
  let element = document.getElementById('scrollUp');
  let positionTop = event.clientY - element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  console.log(positionTop);
}
```

---